# C# listview textbox filter

Tags: c#, listview, filter

```
OrderID  Name  Age
00001    John  15
00002    Alex  20
00003    Josh  13
```

I wanna show a single row in `Listview` after filtering in the `textbox`. For example if I put 00001 in the textbox and click a "search" button, then I see "00001", "John", "15" in the Listview. Anybody know the code for filtering `listview`?

Comment: Code please. This tells us nothing

Comment: Depends on how you wish to store these values and relate them to one another. Code would be helpful, as emd said.